# Given a date find next date which is a particular day of week

Tags: php

Given a date I want to find the next date which is a particular day of week. Eg.

```
Today (8/24/2012)

Find next Sunday(0) returns 8/26/2012
Find next Friday(5) returns 8/24/2012 (Today's a Friday)
```

I can find the day of week for a particular day using:

```
date("w", timeStamp)
```

Comment: Are you referring to strtotime? http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Comment: [What have you tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: I was trying to come up with an algo of my own using date("w", timestamp) but I realised I might be trying to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php):

Calling `strtotime("next Sunday");` will get you the Unix timestamp for next Sunday.

You can give a second parameter to it, which is a Unix timestamp, and the "next Sunday" will be relative to that date.

Comment: Just to point out, if you wanted to get the nearest Friday, using `strtotime("next Friday");` would return next week's Friday and not today. In lieu of this, you can simply just use `strtotime("Friday");` to get the current or upcoming Friday. So if you were to do `date("m/d/y", strtotime("Friday", time()+86400));` you would get the upcoming Friday which would be `08/31/12`